# NodeJS, AngularJS and Mongo creating and updating document returning wrong data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am extending an existing custom application that was built in NodeJS, Angular, MongoDB and the sails framework. I am creating a form for users to order sandwiches.

When the user makes their selection, a javascript object is created that stores the details of the order. That object should be added to the database into an existing "cart" collection.

The issue is that when the javascript object is added to the "cart" collection, it creates a very strange-looking document, it is not at all the data that is supposed to be there.

The following code is based on existing code that successfully updates the cart. The existing code is a dumpster fire that I inherited, and since I'm still learning, debugging this issue has been quite a struggle.

Here's the object that is created when the user fills out the form:

```
//boxlunch object
{"boxlunchType":"Standard Traditional","sandwichesType":"sandwich","sandwichesTotalQty":8,"totalPrice":110,"sandwiches":[{"name":"Chicken Salad","qty":1},{"name":"Grilled Chicken Breast","qty":2},{"name":"Grilled Vegetables Provolone","qty":""},{"name":"Ham and Swiss Cheese","qty":""},{"name":"Roast Beef","qty":5}]}
```

The object is then passed to this function which creates a simple array. The data is passed to a route that performs the database updates.

```
  /*Save boxlunch cart*/
  $scope.saveCartBoxlunch = function(boxlunch) {

    var boxlunchCart = [];
    boxlunchCart.push(
      {
        'quantity' : boxlunch.sandwichesTotalQty,
        'unitprice' : boxlunch.totalPrice,
        'customer_id' : $rootScope.user.displayname,
        'item_name' : boxlunch.boxlunchType
      }
    );

    $sails.post('/boxlunchcart?boxlunch=' + boxlunchCart).then(function (data) {
    });

  };
```

Here is the function that is called by the "boxlunchcart" route.

```
  boxlunchUpdateCart : function (req, res) {
    var boxlunchCartJSON = req.param('boxlunch');

    Cart
      .find(
        {
          customer_id:req.session.user[0].displayname
        }
      )
      .exec(function(err, cartchKObj) {
        if (err) {
          sails.log.error('Error finding cart data',err);
          res.send(500, {title: 'Error finding cart data'});
          //If cart does not exist create new
        } else if (cartchKObj == '' || typeof cartchKObj == 'undefined') {
            Cart
              .create(boxlunchCartJSON)
              .exec(function (err, cartObj){
                sails.log.debug("Cart object: " + cartObj.id);
                if(err){
                  res.send(500, {title: 'error Creating Boxlunch Cart'});
                  sails.log.error('Error Creating Boxlunch Cart',err);
                } else {
                  sails.log.error('Cart Created Successfully',cartObj);
                }
              });
          }
          //If cart exists update existing
          else {
            sails.log.debug("cartchKObj " + cartchKObj[0].id);
                Cart
                  .update( {id : cartchKObj[0].id}, {quantity : 1})
                  .exec(function(err, cartUpdateObj) {
                    sails.log.debug("Cart update object: " + cartUpdateObj.id);
                    if (err) {
                      sails.log.error('Error Updating Boxlunch Cart',err);
                      res.send(500, {title: 'error Updating Boxlunch Cart'});
                    } else {
                      sails.log.debug('Boxlunch Cart Updated Successfully');
                    }
                  });
              }
        });
```

Here's the output of all the sails.log messages.

As you can see, this line prints the new document ObjectID that was created.

```
sails.log.debug("Cart object: " + cartObj.id);

//Output
{"level":"debug","message":"Cart object: 599b63483d6966050026189b","timestamp":"2017-08-21T22:48:40.728Z"}
```

This line prints the new object that was created

```
sails.log.debug('Cart Created Successfully',cartObj);

//Output (added returns for readability)
{"level":"debug","message":"Cart Created Successfully 
{ '0': '[',\n  '1': 'o',\n  '2': 'b',\n  '3': 'j',\n  '4': 'e',\n  '5': 'c',\n  '6': 't',\n  '7': ' ',\n  '8': 'O',\n  '9': 'b',\n  '10': 'j',\n  '11': 'e',\n  '12': 'c',\n  '13': 't',\n  '14': ']',\n  bold: '\\u001b[1m[object Object]\\u001b[22m',\n  
underline: '\\u001b[4m[object Object]\\u001b[24m',\n  strikethrough: '\\u001b[9m[object Object]\\u001b[29m',\n  italic: '\\u001b[3m[object Object]\\u001b[23m',\n  inverse: '\\u001b[7m[object Object]\\u001b[27m',\n  grey: '\\u001b[90m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  black: '\\u001b[30m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  yellow: '\\u001b[33m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  red: '\\u001b[31m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  green: '\\u001b[32m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  blue: '\\u001b[34m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  white: '\\u001b[37m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  cyan: '\\u001b[36m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  
magenta: '\\u001b[35m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  greyBG: '\\u001b[49;5;8m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  blackBG: '\\u001b[40m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  yellowBG: '\\u001b[43m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  redBG: '\\u001b[41m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  greenBG: '\\u001b[42m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  blueBG: '\\u001b[44m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  whiteBG: '\\u001b[47m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  cyanBG: '\\u001b[46m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  magentaBG: '\\u001b[45m[object Object]\\u001b[49m',\n  
rainbow: '\\u001b[31m[\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33mo\\u001b[39m\\u001b[32mb\\u001b[39m\\u001b[34mj\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35me\\u001b[39m\\u001b[31mc\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33mt\\u001b[39m \\u001b[34mO\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35mb\\u001b[39m\\u001b[31mj\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33me\\u001b[39m\\u001b[32mc\\u001b[39m\\u001b[34mt\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35m]\\u001b[39m',\n  zebra: '[\\u001b[7mo\\u001b[27mb\\u001b[7mj\\u001b[27me\\u001b[7mc\\u001b[27mt\\u001b[7m \\u001b[27mO\\u001b[7mb\\u001b[27mj\\u001b[7me\\u001b[27mc\\u001b[7mt\\u001b[27m]',\n  stripColors: '[object Object]',\n  
zalgo: '[̶̮̠̥͈̭̣͎̲̙͇̞̹̘͈̺͉̣̺͍̟͍̦̻̙͔͎̙̘̯̙̥̖̺̱̥̮̬̖̹͎̤̠̗̮̭̙̼̻̼̪̙͉͖̥̞̺̰̲͕͕̠͖̥̉̅̓̇̄ͥͅͅo̷͔̺͈̦̩͇̞̗̣͙̘̬̩̟̫̮̙̜̞̤̺̥͖̯̗̦̞͖̣̳̺̠̥̳̲̣̰̹͖̳̝͚̜̦̥̺͙̣̱̮͉̘̼͈̦̱̞͎͔̱̮̤̤̝͇̠ͦ̽̐͗͒̇̉ͩ͆̐b̞̮͓̭͔̭͈̗̪̤͓͎̰̟͙̤̳̦͇̯̖̣̺͉̠̹̱̪̱̮̙̝͖͇͈̲̘͚͙̻̬͍̩̥̭̲̫̬̲͚̱̟͙̂̒͊̐́̄ͪ̎̒ͥ͑̓͑͂ͯ͠ͅjͨ͋̈ͤ̅̊̚ ҉̰̝̣̮̘̘͉̗̣̥̮͚̭̹̠̥̖̰̟̠̹̜̙̜̻̠̥͍̩̟̳̞̩͉͙̪̖̥̣̩͍͍̜͉͈̣͉̗̝͙͚̘̰͕͉̠̮̩͎̯̖ͅͅe̡̬̤̙̦̼̟͍̘̖̥̜̗̭͈͕͍̞̞̯͇̞̙͔̻̫͓̞̱̭̞̲̊ͮͦ̽̓̽ͤ̒́̍ͪͣͨ̏̚c̟̥̘̤̙̮̺̝͍͍̺̙͍͉̞͍̥̻̪̖̦̳͇̼̫̲̝͙͍̦̖̫̗͙̞͔̻̖̙͈̘̱̩͇̟̻̫̞̮̯̮̰͚͉̞̒͆̌̐̐̾ͩ́̽̾͐͛̐ͯ͗̓̉͘t͗ͤ͆̆͐ͯͧͬ̋ͧ͑ͬͦ̀ͯ̄͋ ҉̺͔̳̟̣̰̙̳̗̗̻̣͍̥̟͓̯͍͕̣͙̱̘̱̰̱͉̤͚̣̠̱̤̞̗̟͔̲̦̤̲̘̬̺̞͔̯̹̝̥̱͇̪̲ͅͅͅͅ ͇̟̠̗͚͔͍̜̟̲̪̳̻̟̭̬̟̝̠̱̥̫̥̳̳͚͕̣͈̼̼̻̼̱̖͙̭͚͓̗͍̥̞̟̀̆ͥ͒̈ͦ̔͋͝ͅO̜̹̮̭͇͎͓̘̺̹̩̱͚̦̯̞̣̣̼̲͖̱̺̠͙͙̹͉̘̻̖̥͓͍̦̰͈̺̮̜̺̝̭̜̗̺̞̣͕̞̤ͦ̌͊̑̅͆͞ͅb̵̲͎̮̦̣̠͎̤͕̬͇̞̹̞̖̪̦͔͍̞̦̖̘̠̙̯̞̲͈̟̻̰̦̭̼̳̲̩͇̫̬̤̰̃͐̊̄j̴̼͉͇̲̺̺̥̣̱͎̭̫̖͎̖̬̺̞̭͓̥̙̻̜̠͍̤̖̩̙̻̦̪̝̣̣̫̝̩͉̥̯̘̗̯̰͉͉͈̭̅ͯ̓̐̇͒̂̔̊͐ͩͣ̅̿ě̷̦͔͈͙̥͈͙̱͚̠͖̣̺̰̘̝̝̤̱̞̗̮̘̭̬͔̼̟̮͎̱̼̬̙̠̤̲͓̠͉̹̼̫͈̘̯͕̗͚̲͓̼͖̺͍̠͙͍̩̓ͪ̔ͮͅc̛͍͈̝͔̰̹͉̖͚̝̻̆̊̅͆ț̨̼̯̟͇̜͇̱̟̝̫͕̩͎̠̤̯͎̘̳͇̳̞̼ͪ͋ͣ͌ͭͣ̍͌ͧ̽͑̉ͦ̌̎ͫͣ]̡̩͈͍͇̪͈̫ͮͮ͆ͧ͛ͫ̎̄̇̊ͫ͒̓̔ͥ̊́̾̑',\n  
silly: '\\u001b[31m[\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33mo\\u001b[39m\\u001b[32mb\\u001b[39m\\u001b[34mj\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35me\\u001b[39m\\u001b[31mc\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33mt\\u001b[39m \\u001b[34mO\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35mb\\u001b[39m\\u001b[31mj\\u001b[39m\\u001b[33me\\u001b[39m\\u001b[32mc\\u001b[39m\\u001b[34mt\\u001b[39m\\u001b[35m]\\u001b[39m',\n  input: '\\u001b[30m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  verbose: '\\u001b[36m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  prompt: '\\u001b[90m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  info: '\\u001b[32m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  blank: '\\u001b[37m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  
data: '\\u001b[90m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  help: '\\u001b[36m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  
warn: '\\u001b[33m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  
debug: '\\u001b[34m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  
error: '\\u001b[31m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  crit: '\\u001b[31m[object Object]\\u001b[39m',\n  id: '599b63483d6966050026189b' }","timestamp":"2017-08-21T22:48:40.730Z"}
```

Question: How can I fix this code such that the data creates the desired document properly?

Update: Perhaps I need to convert the javascript object to a JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, it was because the object was being sent as a request parameter instead of being sent in the request body. I think there must've been some sort of encoding issue when it was sent as a parameter. Lesson learned!

Here are the updates:

```
$sails.post('/boxlunchcart', boxlunchCart).then(function (data) 

var boxlunchCartJSON = req.body;
```